# Duplicate a git repository without the history and still compatible to merge two-ways?

Tags: git

I've a `original` repository that has hardcoded confidential information on the first commits in history.

I want to create a `new` repository from this one, where others developers can work without able to look at the history, and I want to be able to merge from this `new` repository to the `original` and viceversa.

I tried to clone `original` with `depth=1` and then trying to push that with `-f` to the `new` repository, but I got the `shallow update not allowed` error.

I tried with a graft point and `git filter-branch -- --all` but then a `unrelated histories` error appear.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Re: *and I want to be able to merge from this new repository to the original and viceversa* ... you can't. (Well, that's very strong, you *could* with elaborate, rather painful, trickery that you take every time you do a merge, but it's not practical.) You can shrink the repository and/or remove the confidential information, but once you do, the two repositories *will* be unrelated. If you can simply strip out the confidential info (as in the accepted answer) and switch *everyone* to the new repo, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) as I know its saved me a time or two.

**Here's a quick [how-to](https://medium.com/bam-tech/remove-sensitive-information-from-your-git-repository-10cb421f1b84) for you:**

1. Make sure you have Java installed
2. Install [BFG](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.madgag&a=bfg&v=LATEST)
3. Clone your repository, in its entirety, inside a new repo:

   ```
   $ git clone --mirror url/to/your/repo.git
   ```
4. Create a file with a new line for each string you want to remove (each string will be rewritten as **REMOVED** by default):

   ```
   $ echo "my_secret_API_key" >> secret.txt
   $ echo "glob:AWS_*" >> secret.txt (search by glob pattern)
   $ # search by regex pattern and change default rewritten text
   $ echo "regex:password=\w+==>password=" >> secret.txt
   ```
5. Remove the strings you defined above from your repo history with `BFG`:

   ```
   $ bfg --replace-text secret.txt repo.git
   $ cd repo.git
   ```

**Now is the time to verify your history and make sure that everything went smooth:**

1. Clean your repository with all changes we made

   ```
   $ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
   ```
2. Push your changes (forcing is not necessary because you updated every refs)

   ```
   $ git push
   ```

For everyone else using the repo, it should be a simple update with the following:

```
$ git fetch origin/branch
$ git checkout -B branch origin/branch
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything, I've had to actually do this a time or two for clients.

Comment: what does `cs` does? it says command not found on my machine.

Comment: ahh, I made a type, its `cd`, my apologies